# Will 7000+ fonts slow down my system?

Tags: fonts, performance

I've just recently download the whole collection of open source fonts [hosted by Google](http://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/), and was wondering if installing them on my computer would cause performance issues.

The aforementioned computer has a processor clocked at 2.3 GHz and 1.8 GB's of RAM.
If you've had experience with large collections of fonts on Ubuntu, please let me know how your computer preformed in the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should not cause serious performance issues for "normal" use, but as already pointed out some graphics programs need to scan the fonts at startup (because they need more info from the fonts than the fontconfig database provides) and those will start significantly slower, of course.  Also, when fontconfig updates its database (e.g. when you add additional fonts), that might be slower too.

And finding a particular font in the list of available fonts might become a human performance issue...  ;)

So it's probably best to use a font management tool like [font-manager](http://code.google.com/p/font-manager/) or [fontmatrix](http://fontmatrix.net/), so that you can enable/disable individual fonts or groups of fonts.

BTW, you can count the number of currently installed fonts using the following command:

```
$ fc-list | wc -l
2083
```

(Those 2000+ fonts aren't an issue on my system...)

Answer (score 1):

The fonts themselves won't slow down anything but use up some space.

However like WarriorIng64 pointed out some applications, particularly the ones that let you choose fonts are likely to perform a font scan on startup which might slow them down.

Comment: One of the things that GIMP does on startup is scan for fonts, which can take a while even on a fresh install. I wouldn't even want to know how long it would take it to complete with 7000 fonts installed.

Comment: Yea I thought about that as well right now.

Comment: I would be tempted to install ALL THE FONTS (sorry for the maniacal laughter, got distracted there for a bit), and then file bugs on those programs that introduce unnecessary delays.

Comment: Sounds like a plan.